# Pandas Partial String Sort and Quantiles

Tags: pandas, sorting, quantile

i am trying to group the following data into subsets from the following panda DF in the form below and grouped by quarters (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4):

```
  YearMonth  adjusted_power
0    1991Q1    16484.966667
1    1991Q2    14882.566667
2    1991Q3    12983.133333
3    1991Q4    19288.500000
4    1992Q1    19893.600000
5    1992Q2    15904.233333
6    1992Q3    14783.000000
7    1992Q4    18405.500000
8    1993Q1    22045.600000
9    1993Q2    12143.776667
```

I have tried something like this but i cannot obtain the answer i'm looking for. Here are my attempts:

```
q1 = Qdata['YearMonth'].str.contains('Q1').groupby(Qdata['adjusted_power']).quantile(0.25)
Qdata['YearMonth'].str.contains('Q1')['adjusted_power'].quantile(0.25)
```

My final answer should look something like:

```
Q1(0.25) result
Q1(0.50) result
Q1(0.75) result
...
Q4(0.75) result
```

thank you for your help for something that i can try.

Comment: kindly put in concrete values for result in your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to `groupby` quarter and you access the last two character of YearMonth with `str[-2:]` to get the quarter.

```
s = Qdata['adjusted_power'].groupby(Qdata['YearMonth'].str[-2:]).quantile([0.25, 0.5,0.75])
print (s)
YearMonth      
Q1         0.25    18189.283333
           0.50    19893.600000
           0.75    20969.600000
Q2         0.25    13513.171667
           0.50    14882.566667
           0.75    15393.400000
Q3         0.25    13433.100000
           0.50    13883.066666
           0.75    14333.033333
Q4         0.25    18626.250000
           0.50    18847.000000
           0.75    19067.750000
Name: adjusted_power, dtype: float64
```